# Enterprise keywords dialog "Select" button is broken using TaxonomyWebTaggingControl

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, taxonomy, enterprise-keywords

I have an application page which is loaded into a modal and it contains 2 `TaxonomyWebTaggingControl` objects:

[image]

The first control (Categories) is linked to a custom term set, the second (Keywords) is linked to the enterprise keywords term set. The first control works fine, but the one linked to enterprise keywords has a problem with it's "Select: Add Terms" modal dialog, opened by clicking the tag icon - The keywords are correctly listed in that dialog but the select button does nothing and double clicking an item in the modal does nothing either:

[image]

Typing in a value to the control itself does however work correctly:

[image]

The TaxonomyWebTaggingControl is added to the page as follows:

```
<Taxonomy:TaxonomyWebTaggingControl id="KeywordPicker" runat="server" />
```

and then wired up in the code behind:

```
TermStore termStore = taxonomySession.TermStores[MyConstants.TaxonomyTermStoreName];
TermSet keywordTermSet = termStore.KeywordsTermSet;
KeywordPicker.SSPList = termStore.Id.ToString();
KeywordPicker.TermSetList = keywordTermSet.Id.ToString();
KeywordPicker.IsMulti = true;
KeywordPicker.AllowFillIn = true;
KeywordPicker.IsAddTerms = true;
KeywordPicker.IsSpanTermSets = false;
KeywordPicker.IsSpanTermStores = false;
KeywordPicker.IsDisplayPickerButton = true;
KeywordPicker.ExcludeKeyword = false;
```

I'd like users to be able to use the modal dialog to choose keywords as well as type them in manually. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Not so much an answer but I've noticed that the Skills field in the SharePoint Admin version of the edit user profile, the version the user gets in MySites and if you add the Enterprise Keywords field to a list dont allow for pickers to be used. If MS arent adding a picker to these I'm guessing there's a reason it doesnt work. I've also had this problem by the way using the [client side people picker](http://geeks.ms/blogs/lmanez/archive/2014/06/23/using-the-oob-taxonomy-picker-control-just-from-javascript-code-in-sharepoint-online.aspx) . I'm trying to provide Skills editing functionality on

Comment: Check if there is any client side error in the browser?

Comment: @SharePointDev, could you please clarify what do you mean by "Skills field". There is no reference to it in the question itself.

Comment: [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8BdH.gif)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8BdH.gif) Enterprise Tags cannot add exisitng tag though the modal window....
please how to solve it ?